# Modifying HEVC HM reference code

Tags: video, hevc, h.265

I'm very new to the field of HEVC codec. I'm using the HM reference code version 10.1. My task is to limit he CU size to 16x16. So, what i tried was in the configuration file i set the parameters **MaxCUWidth, MaxCUHeight** as 16 and 16 respectively. This ensures that the max CU size is limited to 16x16. However, the next parameter is **QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize and QuadtreeTULog2MinSize**. To ensure that the CU are not sub-divided i.e. to make the MinCUSize to 16x16, i have to set QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize and QuadtreeTULog2MinSize as 4 and 4 respectively(this values i determined using the software manual in the documents part). Hence when i have given 4 and 4 as their values, the code crashes with the errors:

```
Error: Minimum CU width must be greater than minimum transform size

Error: Minimum CU Height must be greater than minimum transform size
```

So now i have to modify the HM reference source code in the function where the input configuration file is parsed. i.e. **TAppEncCfg::xCheckParameter()** function. My problem is i'm not able to figure out where & how the code needs to be changed so that it does not effect other parameters. Any Kind of help regarding the same will be really valuable to me. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To change the CU-size to anything except the default of `64x64`, use these parameters for the encoder `TAppEncoderStatic`

```
--MaxCUWidth=32 \
--MaxCUHeight=32 \
--MaxPartitionDepth=2 \
```

Drop me a comment if you need further assistance

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first thing i tried is the above changes in the configuration file but it didnt meet my requirement bcoz, as specified i need my CU size to be fixed to 16x16, but if above settings are done, then i would get CU of size 16, but the would further divide to form TU of smaller sizes. which i didnt want. So the solution for this is i had to comment a line of code where we check the cost for NxN and set its cost to MAX, as a result 2Nx2N was used and CU size was fixed to 16x16. +1 for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Log base 2 of 16 equals 4.  So your transform size would be 16.  The CU size that you want is a 16 block.  The error tells you that the minimum CU width/height must be (strictly) greater than the minimum transform size.  16 < 16?

You could change the assertion values in the source?  I would recommend a search for "QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize" in TAppEncCfg.cpp.  It will likely lead you to the variable being used later as well as the xConfirmPara that you want to edit.

Hope this is helpful.